# Morphia mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

plz can someone give me an example of code for mapping with mobgodb and morphia.
if this code is correct?

```
@Entity("issues")

class Issue {

  @Id private long id;

  private String desc;

  private String componentName;

  private Date dateCreated = new Date();

}
```

Comment: So ... what happened when tried this code?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia .. This should answer your question

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/annotations/#entity this is an overview on the Entity mapping in Morphia

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abbrivated sample from one of my own question... [Morphia projection behavior for instance variable with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170629/morphia-projection-behavior-for-instance-variable-with-default-value/37171669#37171669)

Your class definition is correct but i would change the @Id from long to String (just going by my experience!)...

A quick sample code for you should be...

```
package com.foo.bar;

@Entity("issues")
class Issue {
   @Id 
   private String id = new ObjectId().toString();
   private String desc;
   private String componentName;
  private Date dateCreated = new Date();
}
```

Then the code to execute this... Omitting all imports...

```
public class Tester
{
    private static Morphia morphia = new Morphia().mapPackage("com.foo.bar.Issue");
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test-db");

        // Create a new issue
        Issue i1 = new Issue();
        i1.setDesc("Sample Description for Issue 1");

        // Save the issue
        ds.save(i1);
        System.out.println("Issue saved with ID : " + i1.getId());

        /* Create and save same more, if you like! */

        // List and Iterate through issues
        List<Issue> issues = ds.createQuery(Issue.class).asList();
        for(Issue issue: issues)
        {
            System.out.println("Issue ID : " + issue.getId() + ", Desc : " + issue.getDesc());
        }

        // Note: Since I have defined the @Id as String, to get a single object based on @Id, you will have to 
        // Issue i2 = ds.get(Issue.class, new ObjectId("ID_HERE"));
    }
}
```

Note that I havent tested this code, wrote it along... But it should work... Use this http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.1/getting-started/quick-tour/ to get a good start on Morphia with MongoDB...

Cheers!